# Storing multiple Image in the directory and database

Tags: sql, reactjs, file-upload

I'm making a small ecommerce project using `Reactjs` and `SQL`. I'm storing two different images `shop(1)` and `user report(2)`

I'm wondering if it's a good idea if I store the `shop images` in the directory itself like this

```
./public
  ./images
    ./shop
     image1.png
     image2.png
  index.html
```

While the `user report` gets uploaded in the `SQL` as a `blob`

Answer (score 2):

If the shop images are only used as static resources for your app, your example is the common way to do it.

However, if the shop images can be added/edited by users or if they shouldn't be visible to everyone, then you should store them in the database similar to the user report images.

Comment: Can everyone access the image if I put on the directory? Only the admin can add/delete/edit those files. I read somewhere that `sql` does not handle multiple blobs very well.

Comment: As is, everyone can view the image (the same way they can view index.html), but they cannot change it. For storing the images, personally I prefer to save them on a Filesystem and instead of storing a blob on the database simply store the path to the image